# Where can I download drivers for lenovo s10-3?

Tags: drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download specific ubuntu drivers for my pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197117/how-to-download-specific-ubuntu-drivers-for-my-pc)

Where can I download drivers for Lenovo s10-3 to make it work in Ubuntu 10.xx?
Or is the XP driver enough to work in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what kind of drivers you are talking about.

Comment: The Linux kernel ships with drivers for most consumer hardware, so unless you have something rather unusual, your machine should run Ubuntu out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

There is a page in the Ubuntu wiki which has information about any issue's and work arounds Here
[Lenovo S10 Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#Lenovo_S10)

As Javier explained it should work without much tweaking but it is a good Idea to try it out first on a USB key or Wubi to make sure everything will run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Xp drivers are useless for Ubuntu (sometimes you can use the wireless one). They are designed for the Windows NT kernel and will not work with the Linux kernel without a major rewrite.

This computer should work with a out-of-the-box (no driver install) with a recent Ubuntu version. But the wisest thing to do is to check it before installing. The install media has an option to check the SO without installing it, use it to play with the computer some time before installing it.

Comment: Some parts of your sentence are not needed. You could just write 'XP drivers are useless!' ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean wifi drivers? If you have already installed Ubuntu you may find that you can try to use some of the drivers for hardware that come with Ubuntu
You will however have to be connected to the internet at the time to enable this to work.

Click on the dash button (top left) or hit alt+f2.

Then type additional drivers and you should see then see an application called 'Additional Drivers'

Click on that and then when it runs see if there are any drivers availble for wireless or graphics card (tends to be those) and press activate if there are.If it is blank then there are none.

Again as the other answers say, let us know what does not work as well eg graphics or wireless or sound etc

If all is working fine and dandy then you are fine.

Again if you have not yet installed it, try a live pen drive version and test to see what works and what does not. It may be for instance that you have issues with your touchpad or multitouch

You may also want to have a look at this wiki which is specifically for the S10-3T (is that what you have?) as well as loads of tips for users on setting it up

[Ubuntu s10-3t wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lenovo_S10-3t)

Hope that helps. If not let us know :)

These helpful chaps have also been playing with Ubuntu on Lenovo S10-3ts

[More Lenovo fun](http://www.lenovos103t.com/2010/06/ubuntu-on-s10-3t.html)