# How to download specific ubuntu drivers for my pc

Tags: drivers, hp

I am using [HP Compaq Presario SG3650IL](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01612606&cc=ad&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001#N66) desktop PC. I am new to Linux so all I want to know that how to download specific drivers for my PC.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what is not working and what drivers you think you need. Most drivers are built into Linux. Go to System Settings > Additional Drivers to see if there are any available for your hardware.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to find and install ASUS motherboard drivers for Linux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184430/where-to-find-and-install-asus-motherboard-drivers-for-linux)

Comment: @dobey Since [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184430/where-to-find-and-install-asus-motherboard-drivers-for-linux) is considerably more specific in scope than this one, it might be better to close *that* as a duplicate of this, and then to ask a moderator to merge the answers.

Comment: @EliahKagan The question isn't really more specific. Merely the simple details of what the PC is, are different. However, the answer is exactly the same for both. Perhaps instead, the other question should be edited to be a bit more generic, rather?

Answer (score 2):

Let Ubuntu decide:

#### In *GNOME Classic*

1. Select "**System**," "**Administration**," "**Hardware Drivers**."
2. Click "**Enable**" to set your selected drivers to use and to include them in future system updates.
3. Select "**System**," "**Administration**," "**Update Manager**" to scan your system for available software and hardware updates.

#### In *Unity* (the default interface)

Open the Dash and search for **System Settings**.

[image]

Open System Settings. In the window that comes up, click on Additional Drivers.

[image]

Alternatively, Ubuntu will automatically perform update scans on a regular basis to ensure that every part of the system is kept up to date with fixes for security and stability problems.